# How to Check double data in sql

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public void AbsenKeluar(){
    loadData();
    if(Name.getText().equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nama tidak boleh kosong");
    }else{
        try{
            Statement stat=(Statement) db_koneksi.getConnect().createStatement();
            String sql="UPDATE data_absensi SET jadwal_keluar = CURRENT_TIME WHERE nama LIKE '%"+nama+"%' AND date = CURRENT_DATE";
            PreparedStatement p =(PreparedStatement) db_koneksi.getConnect().prepareStatement(sql);
            p.executeUpdate();
            getData();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "berhasil absen");
        }catch(SQLException err){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

i have function to abcent, and i don't know how to check if there have name in that date....

Answer (score 1):

If by "double data" you mean duplicates. You can set your column(s) to be unique when you create your scripts.

For example, this statement creates a table with columns ID, Name and Age where ID needs to be unique and cannot be null. That way, you won't need to write any code to check duplicates your DBMS will do that for you

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Age int
);
```

Answer (score 0):

from the way I look its simple tutorial here that you need to do the database connection first then query the result set, after that do the comparing statement of the value (name) that you want. Can refer the other tutorial for that as example. You won't cared much about the date, only if the name is already exist in the database it will check as exist.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a simple way that I would try is something like :

do a SELECT query to the db with the name and that specific date
it will be an additional query execution before updating the db values.

something like this :

```
"SELECT * FROM data_absensi WHERE nama LIKE '%"+nama+"%' AND date = CURRENT_DATE";
```

then check the result, if its returning empty ( that record name is not found ) then you can be sure that this name is not in the database yet for that specific Date, so you can instead do an INSERT query, otherwise if the record is found ( exist ) then you can do your UPDATE query.

remember that the simple SELECT query that you just did also return the id for that name record if you retrieve all columns, so you can use that id field as a PK to update your data.